# Laravel collection return collection with only field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have this Laravel collection with some fields:

```
Collection {#324 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:5 [▼
      "img_src" => "http://newregalospersonales.dev/./svg/regalos-personalizados-gift.svg"
      "img_alt" => "<span>Regalos</span> originales"
      "class" => "personalised-gifts"
      "elements" => array:4 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▶]//element1
        1 => array:2 [▶]//element2
        2 => array:2 [▶]//element3
        3 => array:2 [▶]//element4
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:5 [▼
      "img_src" => "http://newregalospersonales.dev/./svg/love-gifts.svg"
      "img_alt" => "<span>Regalos</span> románticos"
      "class" => "love-gifts"
      "elements" => array:4 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▶]//element1
        1 => array:2 [▶]//element2
        2 => array:2 [▶]//element3
        3 => array:2 [▶]//element4
      ]
    ]
    2 => array:5 [▼
      "img_src" => "http://newregalospersonales.dev/./svg/regalos-ocasiones-especiales.svg"
      "img_alt" => "<span>Detalles</span><br>de boda"
      "class" => "wedding"
      "elements" => array:4 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▶]//element1
        1 => array:2 [▶]//element2
        2 => array:2 [▶]//element3
        3 => array:2 [▶]//element4
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

And I only get the collection with the field 'elements'.

I want an result like this:

```
Collection {#324 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▶] //element1
        1 => array:2 [▶ //element2 
        2 => array:2 [▶] //element3
        3 => array:2 [▶] //element4
    ]
    1 => array:4 [▼

        0 => array:2 [▶] //element1
        1 => array:2 [▶] //element2
        2 => array:2 [▶] //element3
        3 => array:2 [▶] //element4
    ]
    2 => array:4 [▼

        0 => array:2 [▶] //element1
        1 => array:2 [▶] //element2
        2 => array:2 [▶] //element3
        3 => array:2 [▶] //element4
    ]
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to do this?
I´m using Laravel 5.3 version and I not have idea about that collection filter use for this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) method:

```
$plucked = $collection->pluck('elements');
```

> The pluck method retrieves all of the values for a given key.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `pluck()` method.

You can use it like this:

```
$collection->pluck('field');
```

[More about it](http://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck)

Answer (score 1):

You can use laravel's `pluck()` method to fetch the selected keys from the collection like this:

```
$plucked_items = $collection->pluck('elements'); // returns a collection
$plucked_items_arr = $plucked_items->all(); // returns an array
```

Hope this helps!